# As an American, can I apply for an Algerian visa in Morocco?

Tags: visas, us-citizens, morocco, algeria

I'm an American citizen in Morocco. Can I apply for an Algerian tourist visa at the Algerian consulate in Casablanca (or Oujda)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the rules ([here](http://www.mae.gov.dz/Visa.aspx), in French), you have to be resident in the country where you apply. The key paragraph is the first:

> Les étrangers désireux de se rendre en Algérie doivent présenter à
> leur arrivée un passeport en cours de validité muni d’un visa d’entrée
> sur le territoire Algérien délivré par l’Ambassade ou le Consulat
> algérien du lieu de résidence habituel du demandeur. A l’exception des
> pays où les formalités de visa ne sont pas exigées (voir liste des
> pays).
>
> Listes des pays non soumis aux formalités de visa: TUNISIE, MAROC, MAURITANIE, LYBIE, YÉMEN, MALI, MALAISIE, RASD, SEYCHELLES, SYRIE

A rough, fairly liberal, translation is (emphasis mine):

> Foreigners wishing to enter Algeria should present on arrival a valid
> passport affixed with an entry visa for Algeria, delivered by the
> Algerian Embassy or Consulate in their **habitual place of
> residence**. This is with the exception of countries with no visa required (see list).
> List of countries: Tunisia, Morocco, Mauritania, Libya, Yemen, Mali, Malaysia, the SADR, the Seychelles and Syria

So to answer your question, unless you are habitually resident in Morocco, you technically cannot apply for an Algerian visa there.

Comment: Good find. That's not actually a list of countries without Algerian diplomatic representation, though: it's the list of countries whose citizens are eligible for visa-free entry to Algeria!

Comment: Whoops! Sorry about that, my french is a little rusty.